# Generating (PHP-)Code with Scala

Tags: scala, code-generation, generator

I want to generate PHP-code from a Model I created from parsing a WSDL-File.
Anyone an advice how to generate PHP-Code in a smart way?

Thanks

Comment: Well, regardless of what you plan to do, using PHP is most likely the wrong way.

Comment: I think he is trying to _avoid_ using php by automatically generating it. ;)

Comment: may be u could use some template engine (http://scalate.fusesource.org/documentation/user-guide.html).

Comment: absolutely right, kim! ;) And it works like a charm ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had pretty good results using Johannes Rudolph's [scala-enhanced-strings](http://github.com/jrudolph/scala-enhanced-strings) plugin to generate source code.

Comment: Are there any other good template-engines suitable for code-generation (not HTML-centric) ?